# Use GLM in R to see if sex ratio varies by group

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I have data on how things developed in the laboratory. This involves different collection site information and different treatments.

My question here: Did the groupings (place and treatment) have an effect on the resulting sex ratio of adult males to females? Can I figure this out using GLM?

[I don't know how many people of each sex I entered. It was random, some juveniles died during development and I only designated the sex of the adults]

I followed this tutorial and I used GLM to investigate the sex ratios: http://www.simonqueenborough.info/R/stats-basic/glm.html

Here is my data and code:

```
mo<-"Temp   Locality    Females Males
A   APR 88  110
B   APR 101 97
C   APR 85  94
A   ARS 65  69
B   ARS 57  78
C   ARS 54  76
A   RMO 103 90
B   RMO 97  101
C   RMO 82  78
A   RPV 89  92
B   RPV 98  86
C   RPV 64  76
A   SJU 66  63
B   SJU 57  66
C   SJU 16  17
A   TLC 45  46
B   TLC 41  43
C   TLC 27  44
A   TPN 25  20
B   TPN 22  25
C   TPN 16  22"

data <- read.table(text=mo, header = TRUE)
y<-cbind(data$Males,data$Females)
model<-glm(y~data$Temp+data$Locality, family=binomial)
summary(model)

#results of summary (model)
Call:                       
glm(formula = y ~ sexy$Temp + sexy$Locality, family = binomial)                     

Deviance Residuals:                         
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max                         
-0.8231  -0.5549  -0.2398   0.5038   1.2954                         

Coefficients:                       
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)                       
(Intercept)       0.03839    0.09885   0.388    0.698                       
sexy$TempB        0.03032    0.09093   0.333    0.739                       
sexy$TempC        0.14538    0.09818   1.481    0.139                       
sexy$LocalityARS  0.14092    0.13098   1.076    0.282                       
sexy$LocalityRMO -0.13872    0.11938  -1.162    0.245                       
sexy$LocalityRPV -0.07783    0.12213  -0.637    0.524                       
sexy$LocalitySJU -0.01914    0.14600  -0.131    0.896                       
sexy$LocalityTLC  0.07243    0.15286   0.474    0.636                       
sexy$LocalityTPN -0.03022    0.19444  -0.155    0.877
```

From both model summaries, I found no significant difference in sex ratio by temperature or locality. Is this correct? Is GLM the appropriate method or should I take another approach?

Comment: It is probably correct.  Maybe there just isn't a significant difference.  Why would you think there has to be? Since this is simulated data it depends on how you simulated the number of males and females in each temperature group and locality rather than glm not working properly.

Comment: Ok, just wondering if there was anything better out there. The numbers weren't simulated and a cursory look made me think there were some significant effects.

Comment: I see when you said it was random you meant that it looked random.